# WPF user control generator

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I want to generate a user control with textboxes labels and other primary controls and allow  the user to manipulate the design (Drag drop , change properties etc... ) of the control.

Is there any free framework to do it or some thing similar?

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is Expression Blend; these are some links of the product: [Expression Blend 4 MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296227.aspx) - [Blend Overview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) - [Blend Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend).